# Restarting the code on waking from background

Tags: ios

The essence of the application is that to compare with the current date, and specify the output text (prayer times) for each day. **The problem**: when the app is in the background text for the current day shows. If you close the application and open after all the shows correctly.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *utr;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *voskh;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *obed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *predz;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *vecher;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *noch;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comp0 = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateComponents *comp1 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *comp2 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *comp3 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *comp4 = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [comp1 setDay:1]; [comp1 setMonth:1];
    [comp2 setDay:2]; [comp2 setMonth:1];
    [comp3 setDay:3]; [comp3 setMonth:1];
    [comp4 setDay:4]; [comp4 setMonth:1];

    if([comp1 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp1 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

        _utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"11:58"; _predz.text=@"14:12"; _vecher.text=@"16:31"; _noch.text=@"18:01";
    }

    if([comp2 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp2 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

       _utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"11:58"; _predz.text=@"14:13"; _vecher.text=@"16:31"; _noch.text=@"18:01";
    }

    if([comp3 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp3 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

        _utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"11:59"; _predz.text=@"14:14"; _vecher.text=@"16:32"; _noch.text=@"18:02";
    }

    if([comp4 day]   == [comp0 day] &&
       [comp4 month] == [comp0 month] ) {

        _utr.text=@"05:44"; _voskh.text=@"07:19"; _obed.text=@"12:00"; _predz.text=@"14:15"; _vecher.text=@"16:33"; _noch.text=@"18:03";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `applicationWillEnterForeground:` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623076-applicationwillenterforeground?language=objc) or register for the corresponding NSNotification, and take this opportunity to update your interface.